# MySQL constraint to allow duplicates but prevent different combination of values in two column

Tags: mysql, constraints, check-constraints

A table in MySQL 8.0 where only one distinct combination of two values can exist. It can exist multiple times.

Example:
[image: result]

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qbeEysSnRiEbAqBDh1ZcUs/1)

Is there a way to do this without triggers?

- **UNIQUE CONSTRAINT** won't work (duplicates need to be allowed)
- **CHECK CONSTRAINT**, I can't find a way to make this work, I'd need to run a query with the check to ensure that the combination is distinct, and that's not possible.
- **FUNCTIONAL CONSTRAINT**, I also can't find a way to make this work

If there's no way apart from triggers, would a trigger keep ACID properties? What performance hit should I expect?

Comment: I don't think there's a way without triggers.

Comment: This seems like a normalization problem. There should be a separate table with `lot_id, invoice_id` where `lot_id` is unique, and this table should have a foreign key to it.

Comment: @Barmar is something like this what you had in mind https://pasteboard.co/F1cM4MM4tEfD.jpg? Seems a bit odd to me to need to add a table just to facilitate this. But I can't argue with relational algebra, can I?

Comment: I think so. Google database normalization.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your limited sample, I suggest adding a column called row_num, then add this:

```
UNIQUE(lot_id, row_num)
```

Note that `UNIQUE` handles `NULLs` differently than `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Sorry, I voted on this too quickly, assuming that by row_num you meant the id column ‍♂️ (If you edit the question, I'll be able to change it)

Adding the row number column and this key would work. I'll look into how I could automate this in the database without needing to tweak the underlying application. In that case it might be a good alternative to the normalisation approach. 

Comment: @TonyVlcek - No, I do mean `row_num` -- it seems to be available for each item.  And it can be used to solve the problem as stated.  I don't think `id` will work